# How to convert files Azure Logic Apps using 'Convert Word Document to PDF'?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I need to convert word documents to PDF whenever a file is created or modified at Sharepoint. I've seen the component "Convert Word Document to PDF", but when I run the logic app and modify a file, an error shows up.  So, what I really want is to convert ALL files I create/modify to PDF, not just one file.

```
Bad Request.
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "There was an error accessing the file. Please try again or select a different file.\r\nclientRequestId: 484f1273-df35-4e9d-881b-086fce0c7ab3",
  "source": "wordonlinebusiness-we.azconn-we.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

Screenshot of my logic app.

[image]

Comment: Yes. You can create the same file on OneDrive, and OneDrive has a connector which allows you to convert a file to pdf. Then you can create a new file at sharepoint with the file you got from the conversion of OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

The action `Convert Word Document to PDF`, it can't convert doc from the `triggerBody`, it converts doc file from a location.

You could use other connectors to do it like `Plumsail Documents` or `Encodian`, I test with `Plumsail Documents`.Before you use this, you need to go to this [site](https://account.plumsail.com) to register an account to get the API key.The whole flow would be like the below picture shows.

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.